# how does laptop regulator circuit works

Tags: mosfet

Regards. My question is why this regulator uses 4 mosfets (which is the role of the lower mosfet) .I do not understand why two lower mosfets are needed (because when the signal comes to the gate b++ trece is connected to ground through mosfet resistance ) the output voltage will drop[image]

Comment: Unclear question. If you're asking why it uses 4 instead of 2, the answer is power sharing. Or are you asking about the topology more generally?

Comment: I do not understand why two lower mosfets are needed (because when the signal comes to the gate b++ trece is connected to ground through mosfet resistance ) the output voltage will drop

Comment: No, the output voltage will not drop, note that there's also an **inductor** between CPU_CORE and the drains of those NMOS. That inductor is a **crucial** component in a DCDC converter.

Comment: It is a simple totem-pole design PWM power supply. The pairing of mosfets is as stated above-power sharing. Study totem-pole designs using various transistors, then this design will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking what the lower MOSFETs are for. This is a **synchronous buck regulator**, and now you know the right term, you can read about them to your heart's content. The MOSFETs take the place of the diode you see in a normal buck regulator. This allows a lower voltage drop which can be significant in a low voltage power supply. The tradeoff is complexity.

There's a hint toward the term **synchronous rectification** in the name of the ISL6207 driver IC, from the datasheet: "High Voltage Synchronous Rectified Buck MOSFET Driver".

Comment: thanks for answering if I understood well the lower mosfet serves to close the circuit when upper dont work (in essence to allow inductor to supply energy to load )